# how to open the url in the same page

Tags: javascript

```
let url ='https://www.google.com/search?q='+document.getElementById('search').value;
             window.open(url)
```

This works fine but I want to open this in the same tab

so when I use
`window.open(url,"_self")`
or

```  window.location.href =url; ````

it just reloads the same page

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this:

```js
window.location.assign(url);
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

Comment: Which has the same effect as `window.location.href` which, according to OP, does _"just reloads the same page"_

Comment: While it doesn't make sense it doesn't seem to work with `.href`, but using `.assign` is better, as it is a method unlike `.href`, imo.

Comment: It doesn't make sense because the question lacks a bunch of information. And without those information (a.k.a. [mcve]) that problem doesn't exist -> OP does something else that "breaks" that function